# Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "record does not start with '@'"

Tags: r, plyr, bioconductor, domc

I want to use doMC package of R to read the fastq file, but I meet this problem.

> Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "record does not start with '@'"
>
> Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "internal: buf != "

My code is

```
library(ShortRead)
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
library(plyr)
fastq_file <- '../quantibio/data/SRR038848.fastq'
n_cores <- 2
registerDoMC(n_cores)
parallel <- T
if(n_cores==1) parallel <- F
n_lines <- countLines(fastq_file)
n_reads <- n_lines/4
threshold=1e5
n_chuncks <- ceiling(n_reads/threshold)
fq <- FastqStreamer(fastq_file, threshold)
chunck_out <- llply(1:n_chuncks, function(ii){
  f <- yield(fq)
  width_max <<- max(width(f))
  # chunck_list <-  .proc_chunk(f, width_max)
  f
  
}, .parallel=parallel,
.paropts = list(.export = c('fq'), .packages=c('ShortRead', 'Biostrings') ))
close(fq)
```

Comment: `yield(fq)` expects to iterate through the file, so evaluating in parallel doesn't make sense -- the reader will not be positioned at the correct location in the file. Also the code is not written to be re-entrant. A more typical way to parallelize is across files, with one streamer per file, iterating in parallel. Better to ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org)